# I am new to kafka streams, How to do summation with json data {"ename":"abc","sal":"10000"} {"ename":"xyz","sal":"10000"}

Tags: json, apache-kafka, stream

How to do summation with json data {"ename":"abc","sal":"10000"} {"ename":"xyz","sal":"10000"}

Comment: What exactly do you want to summarize? `sal` fields?

Comment: input is [{“ename”:“abc”,“sal”:“10000”}, {“ename”:“xyz”,“sal”:“10000”},{“ename”:“abc”,“sal”:“10000”},{“ename”:“xyz”,“sal”:“10000”}] then output is {“ename”:“abc”,“sal”:“20000”}  {“ename”:“xyz”,“sal”:“20000”} in kafka streams only